# How to store IP Address range vs location

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a problem i have ip address range

```
IP                                    Location
10.1.100.200- 10.1.100.800              x
10.1.101.200- 10.1.101.800              Y
10.1.102.200- 10.1.102.800              Z etc etc
```

Now given an ip I want to find location like eg 10.1.101.270 should give Y
I dont want the code I am trying to use best algorithm to store and search them?
How to approach this

```
B+Tree?
```

Comment: Do you have to parse that, or values are already stored somewhere?

Comment: Your ranges are overlapping, is this intended?

Comment: If you have "records" with that data, you could keep them in an array, which you sort. A binarySearch() with a custom comparator will either return the correct one or it will return the negative value from which you can figure out the match.   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T[], T, java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use, [**`TreeMap<K, V>`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lowerEntry%28K%29): You can store the start range to map the location.  `TreeMap` uses Red-Black tree data structure for ordering the entry. Where the key finding operations including inseritng and removing are `O(log n)`. This map provides two useful function:

[**`higherEntry(K key)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#higherEntry%28K%29):  Returns a `key-value` mapping associated with the least `key` strictly greater than the given key, or `null` if there is no such key.

[**`lowerEntry(K key)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lowerEntry%28K%29): Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key strictly less than the given key, or `null` if there is no such key.

While searching with an specific ip as `key`, You can try find this left and right entry containing the `start ip-range` as key and their corresponding location as value.  Compare against these ip-range with the searching `key`  to determine the value `V`(location).

Comment: How to map the IP start and end?Key and value?

Comment: @sandy, yes. `TreeMap` keeps its data in ordered based upon the `key`. As i have mentioned in the answer, you can probably work by saving all the start range as key and corresponding location as value to work with

Answer (score 4):

What about a [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or a [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)? Interval Tree should be better if your "set" of IP address ranges are dynamic; Segment Tree should be better if the ranges are static and it is said to be better with "stabbing queries" which it seems like you are performing.

Interval Tree:

> In computer science, an interval tree is an ordered tree data
>   structure to hold intervals. Specifically, it allows one to
>   efficiently find all intervals that overlap with any given interval or
>   point. It is often used for windowing queries.

Query time of O(log n)

Segment Tree:

> In computer science, a segment tree is a tree data structure for
>   storing intervals, or segments. It allows querying which of the stored
>   segments contain a given point.

Query a point in O(log n + k), k being the number of retrieved intervals or segments.

Implementations:

Segment tree [implementation in Java](http://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/SegmentTree.java).

Interval Tree [implementation in Java](http://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/IntervalTree.java).

Comment: can i do search faster in log n?

Comment: I almost post about creating a structure like the segment tree, without knowing that it even existed. Great to know that it is something already studied.

Comment: @sandy I've added the query time to the answer.

Comment: @DNax That's what I love about SO, you can learn something new or validate a passing thought on a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a TreeMap as Sage suggested.
Assume there will be no overlap.

```
public class IPSegment implements Comparable<IPSegement>{

    private long start;
    private long end;
    public IPSegement(String startIp, String endIp){
         //convert the ip address to a 32 bit integer. 

    }
    public int compareTo(IPSegement other){

         return this.start - other.start;  //assume no overlap
    }

    public int equals(IPSegement other){
      // check both start and end
    }

    public boolean contains(long ip){
      //check whether 'ip' is in this range
    }
}


public class IPSegmentMap{
     private TreeMap<IPSegement> map = new TreeMap<IPSegement>();
     public void add(String start, String end, String location){
          //...
     }

     public String find(String ipAddress){
         long ip = convertIPtoInt(ipAddress);
         IPSegement request = new IPSegement(ip,ip);
         IPSegement exist = map.floorKey(request);
         if(exist.contains(ip)){
             return map.get(exist);
         }

     }

}
```